# Convergence of oscillatory integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following code, which does an integration of an oscillatory integral:

```
c = 3*10^8;(*m/s*)

lamL = 1064*10^(-9);(*m*)

omL = c/lamL*2*Pi;(*1/s*)

xmxs = 5;(*m*)

m = 10^(-5)/(197*10^6*10^(-15));(*1/m*)

kL = 2*Pi/lamL;(*1/m*)

t = 120;(*s*)

kphi = Sqrt[kL^2 - m^2];(*1/m*)

u = Sqrt[c^2*(t - ts)^2 - xmxs^2];(*m*)

Integrand = BesselJ[1, m*u]/u*Exp[-I*omL*ts]

 NIntegrate[Integrand, {ts, -Infinity, t - 1/c*xmxs}, 
  Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo"]
```

I can already see from the output that the integral does not converge, since I get very different results, when I do the integration twice.

How can I make this more stable? I can also wait a few minutes to get the result. Until now I have tried to incease the number of points that the integration function evaluates with " MaxPoints", but this seems not to work.

Do you have an idea how to get better convergence?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, use natural units, where all parameters are of order 1. Especially when doing numeric work!

Answer (score 1):

A simple substitution seems to conquer the oscillations:

```
vsub = Last@Solve[v == Sqrt[-25 + 90000000000000000 (120 - ts)^2], ts]
(*  {ts -> (36000000000 + Sqrt[25 + v^2])/300000000}  *)

iv = Integrand*Dt[ts] /. vsub /. Dt[v] -> 1 // Simplify[#, v > 0] &
(*
  ((-1)^(124/133) E^(-(250000000/133) I π Sqrt[25 + v^2])
    BesselJ[1, (10000 v)/197])/(300000000 Sqrt[25 + v^2])
*)

Sqrt[-25 + 90000000000000000 (120 - ts)^2] /.
 {{ts -> -Infinity}, {ts -> t - 1/c*xmxs}}
(*  {∞, 0}  *)

NIntegrate[iv, {v, Infinity, 0}]
(*  -1.18009*10^-14 - 8.12346*10^-15 I  *)
```

Check for stability at a higher working precision:

```
NIntegrate[iv, {v, Infinity, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*  -1.1800930301930403194*10^-14 - 8.1234583706679614906*10^-15 I  *)

NIntegrate[iv, {v, Infinity, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 24, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]
(*  -1.18009303019304031940817*10^-14 - 8.12345837066796149061502*10^-15 I  *)
```

Comment: If I had to guess why this works, I would say it's because the substitution eliminates a weak singularity at `ts = t - 1/c*xmxs` where the square root vanishes, which also happens to be where the integrand has its largest amplitude. At least that's the idea that led me to try it.